# Understanding c# random variable generation

Tags: c#

I am review some C# code, and I am not a C# programmer.  I am looking at randomness in it.

I have the following code:

```
Random random = new Random(Convert.ToInt32((cell[0] << 20) | (cell[1] << 10) | cell[2]));
```

If i am reading this right, There is an if statement inside the random generator.  My question is what does this do? I'm trying to rebuild it into python, for the functionality and whenever I search random I see things like:

```
Random random = new Random()
random.next(3)
```

My first thought was the above would set the randomness factors, but i think I am off on that.  cause what I have seen online, says that is defined by the random.next part. Has anyone dealt with code like this before?

thanks in advance.

Comment: **[Random class constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#constructors)**

Comment: As well as the Random constructor - this may be useful too [Left Shift Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/left-shift-operator)  and [Bitwise Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx)

Comment: The value is an random seed. This is not specific to c#, more or less all pseudo number generators have it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

Comment: The call to `Convert.ToInt32` is unusual and that's the part I would want to dig into to understand the intent of the original programmer. What's the type of `cell`?

Comment: I am doing this as part of a challenge so I dont want to give away the answers to anyone else who may be on here, But i agree.  with the convert.toint32.  The cell is a list of uints that are brought over from a different function.  I have most of this rebuilt in python, but I dont think its working the same way.

Answer (score 9):

> There is an if statement inside the random generator.

No; it just builds the seed (instead of using the clock) using the values from 3 cells; the `<<` is left-shift and `|` is bitwise "or", so: `cell[0] << 20) | (cell[1] << 10) | cell[2]` just builds an integer from 3 values. So: as long as the values in those 3 cells are identical, the random sequence generated will be identical. If the values in the cells are different, then the random sequence will *probably* change (although isn't strictly guaranteed to).

Answer (score 2):

The parameter in the first example is the seed and not a 'randomness factor'

If you do not provide a seed then it takes the system clock I believe

Think of the seed as a magic number from which all the numbers in the 'random' sequence are generated